# PHPUnit - autoload classes within tests

Tags: php, phpunit

I have the following structure within my project:

```
/
/app
/app/models/ --UserTable.php

/lib
/lib/framework
/lib/framework/Models
/lib/framework/Db

/tests -- phpunit.xml, bootstrap.php
/tests/app
/tests/app/models --UserTableTest.php
```

With the app and lib directories I have various classes that work together to run my app. To setup my tests I have create a /tests/phpunit.xml file and a /tests/bootstrap.php

phpunit.xml

```
<phpunit bootstrap="bootstrap.php">
</phpunit>
```

bootstrap.php

```
<?php

function class_auto_loader($className)
{
  $parts = explode('\\', $className);
  $path = '/var/www/phpdev/' . implode('/', $parts) . '.php';

  require_once $path;
}

spl_autoload_register('class_auto_loader');
```

So I have the following test:

```
<?php

class UserTableTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  protected $_userTable;

  public function setup()
  {
    $this->_userTable = new app\models\UserTable;
  }

  public function testFindRowByPrimaryKey()
  {
    $user = $this->_userTable->find(1);

    $this->assertEquals($user->id, 1);
  }
}
```

But it can't find the class when I run the test - `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'app\models\UserTable' not found in /var/www/phpdev/tests/app/models/UserTableTest.php on line 13`

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to understand PHPUnit configuration better so I opted to write the configuration and bootstrap file myself.

Comment: Add `var_dump($path)` just before the `require_once` to make sure your autoloader is being called.

Comment: Unrelated, but you can use `str_replace('\\', '/', $path)` instead of `explode` and `implode`.

Comment: It seems I have to write `phpunit --configuration tests/phpunit.xml tests/`. Do I need to write this in full every time? Also, now it's loading my application classes OK but I'm getting a new error - `Failed opening required '/var/www/phpdev/PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase.php'`. Is my bootstrap autoloader causing issues with loading this PHPUnit class? If I remove it, I can't load my app classes.

Comment: Also, it seems this error only occurs when the assertion doesn't pass - otherwise fine.

Answer (score 35):

If you are using composer autoload

change

`<phpunit colors="true" strict="true" bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">`

to

`<phpunit colors="true" strict="true" bootstrap="tests/autoload.php">`

and in `tests` directory create new `autoload.php` with following content

```
include_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$classLoader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
$classLoader->addPsr4("Your\\Test\\Namespace\\Here\\", __DIR__, true);
$classLoader->register();
```

Comment: Solved my problem too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This fixed relative path, though it answers this question, makes far too many assumptions about the structure of the application the package is being tested in. Is there a more dynamic or flexible way (with some auto discovery) way to do this?

Comment: Even Simpler solution would be to configure autoload-dev for your tests folder `https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload-dev`

Comment: @Raaghu best solution to use an alternative autoloader for dev. +1

Answer (score 5):

You probably should use composer to organize your code, for example, the composer.json in your project root directory should contains something like:

```
  ...
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "PRJ_NAME\\APP\\": "app/",
      "PRJ_NAME\\LIB\\": "lib/"
    }
  },
  ...
```

Then after run composer update, the two namespaces defined above are put into the vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php. Next is simple, just run phpunit with the autoload option like this:

```
phpunit --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php tests/app/models/UserTableTest
```

Make sure change the usage of your namespace in both your source code and test code.

Comment: If you are using composer, then this is the best answer IMHO.

Comment: I really wish this worked, but still class not defined in phpunit but autoloads everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

If you load you classess with the same bootstrap in app you should be able to load them in tests. If you are running test by cd into your test directory just add to your phpunit.xml:

```
<testsuite name="My Application Tests">
    <directory>./</directory>
</testsuite>
```

Inside `<phpunit></phpunit>`

Answer (score 1):

In my *loader* (very close to yours) I check if the first exploded part of the class name is my *vendor*, if it isn't the *loader* just return doing nothing (else had issues with *phpunit*'s *loader*, since I'm a newbie of *phpunit* and don't know if this is the expected behavior nor if *phpunit* suggest or provide a *loader* ready to use).

I keep `phpunit.xml` in the same directory of `tests/` (not within) and once configured `<directory>tests</directory>` I just run `phpunit` on command line without configuration or directory options.