# [PHP/Symfony2][Tests] Functional test issue with PHPUnit

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, phpunit, functional-testing

I try to make some tests for my project but I have issue.
When I launch Unit tests with PHPUnit it's works perfectly but when I try to do functional tests (with `extends WebTestCase`), there is an error.

I run `phpunit -c app/ src/path/to/my/fileTest.php`:

```html
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPUnit\Runner\Exception: Class 'src/Eat/MainBundle/Tests/Controller/PaiementControllerTest' could not be found in '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PopLink/Symfony/src/Eat/MainBundle/Tests/Controller/PaiementControllerTest.php'. in phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php:101
Stack trace:
#0 phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php(130): PHPUnit\Runner\StandardTestSuiteLoader->load('src/Eat/MainBun...', '/Applications/M...')
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php(73): PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner->loadSuiteClass('src/Eat/MainBun...', '/Applications/M...')
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php(162): PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner->getTest('src/Eat/MainBun...', '/Applications/M...', Array)
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php(141): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run(Array, true)
#4 /usr/local/bin/phpunit(546): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
#5 {main}
  thrown in phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php on line 101
```

I have read some topics about this error but I still don't understand.
Can you help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: do you have a phpunit.xml in your app folder? What are the contents of your composer.json ?

Comment: Yes I have a phpunit.xml in my app/ folder but it was not auto-generated. I written it myself.

Comment: Looks like autoloading is not work did you load your composers vendor/autoload.php file in your phpunit.xml or try  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219764/phpunit-autoload-classes-within-tests

Comment: try with `phpunit -c app --filter=fileTest`