# Eclipse PDT - Filesystem changes or new Composer autoload paths break autoloader

Tags: php, filesystems, require, autoload

I am making a project in Composer *using Eclipse PDT*, however every time that I add a file to a directory below a composer autoload base directory the phpunit test runner can no longer find my files.

At least 2 times I have done some tinkering and got it working again but seemingly it breaks every time I make a filesystem change. I would like the Composer autoloader to find my files regardless of fs changes.

Here is my latest autoloader config:

```
{
    "name": "someone/webapp",
    "description": "",
    "require-dev":  {
        "phpunit/phpunit":"~9.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.0"
    },
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.7"
    },
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4": {
            "WebApp\\": "src/"
         }
    },
    "autoload-dev" : {
        "psr-4": {
            "WebApp\\Tests\\" : "tests/"
        }
    }
}
```

I previously tried my autoloader with the PSR-0 compliant standard:

```
{
     "name": "srmes/shopping-app-test",
     "description": "Developer test. Basic OO-orientated PHP webapp",
     "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit":"~9.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.0"
     },
     "require": {
         "doctrine/orm": "~2.7"
     },
    "autoload" : {
         "classmap": ["src/", "src/Models/"],
         "psr-0": {
             "WebApp\\": "src/",
             "WebApp\\Models\\": "src/Models/"
         }
    },
    "autoload-dev" : {
         "classmap": ["tests/", "tests/Models/"],
         "psr-0": {
             "WebApp\\Tests\\" : "tests/"
         }
    }
}
```

My question refers to adding files to autoloading directories. My directory structure looks like this:

```
someone/webapp
|-vendor
| |-MISC_PACKAGES
|- src --autoloader base dir
| |-Models
| | |-Product.php
| | |-Furniture.php
| |- IComparable.php -- THIS WAS ADDED, BREAKING AUTOLOADER
|- tests -- autoloader base dir
| |- Models
| | |- FurnitureTest.php
| | |- IProductTest.php
| |-bootstrap.php
```

**Edit:**

As shown in my comment below I have found this issue to be to do with the Eclipse PDT autocompletion only working once a commit has been made to git with the subsequent new composer `require` statements etc., which is less than ideal for me as I would like to experiement with packagist packages before committing

Comment: You should not change the files by yourself, but let composer do the work. AFAIK, Test paths can be inserted. If you have, try PhpStorm IDE who has support for that in the latest 2020.1 version.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'inserted', should I create files in my autoloader directories via a composer command?

Comment: When you start a project with composer init and add your packages with composer require <package>, then composer manages that files. See [config](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md). (search for test) This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219764/phpunit-autoload-classes-within-tests) may also be helpful.

Comment: Requiring packages and bootstrapping phpunit are not what I was trying to ask with this question, but maybe it was unclear I have added an update :)

Comment: Place IComparable.php into a directory suggesting "Interfaces" . This can not be on a "root" path, because the autoloader does not find it.

Comment: I cannot answer this yet but it seems that Eclipse PDT can only autocomplete composer autoloader paths once a commit has been made to git (locally or remotely also, I don't think it matters). I can add packages to `require`, `composer dumpautoload` and nothing on Eclipse, but then it shows up later when I commit

Answer (score 2):

## Composer/PHPUnit problem

You problem have nothing to Eclipse PDT itself. In your composer you registered classmap and PSR-0. Classmap require composer to rescan your directory to find new classes [1].

PSR-4 for your src/ directory will be enough. If you create for example create WebApp\Service\Foo class in src/Service/Foo.php autoloader (phpunit for example) will find it.

**Warning**: If you use `"optimize-autoloader": true` or run `composer install` with `--optimize-autoloader` or dump-autoload with `--optimize` your PSR4/PSR-0 will be transformed to classmap !!!

I assume that you correctly registered composer autoloder as phpunit bootstrap.

## Eclipse PDT Problem

You don't have to remove/add composer support each time, but because you run composer update outside eclipse you have to perform additional tasks after each `composer install` or `composer update`:

1. F5 (refresh) on project to make sure eclipse is synced with files system. If you have auto-sync enabled will be working correctly
2. Right `click on project -> composer -> update build path`
3. Sometimes project clean is also required

Auto-sync not work for now, see my bug: bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=515742

[1] - https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap

Comment: I did say in the question that I also tried with PSR-4. I changed `composer.json` to PSR-4, and would try commands like: `composer dumpautoload`, `composer update` and on Eclipse remove then replace composer support ([root_project_folder]->configure->add/remove Composer support), update build path etc. Since adding the bounty I have gone into properties and checked the build path. It turns out that the build path was often old, and didn't match my composer autoloader's vendor namespaces, so I disagree with your assertion I'm afraid

Comment: You asked for php unit:  "the phpunit test runner can no longer find my files". Now you talking about composer support in PDT so I'm confused.

Comment: You don't have to remove/add composer support each time, but because you run composer update outside eclipse you have to perform additional task: 
1. F5 (refresh) on project to make sure eclipse is synced with files system. If you have auto-sync enabled will be working correctly
2. Right click on project -> composer -> update build path
Auto-sync not work for now, see my bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=515742

Comment: As I said in answer, PDT have nothing to composer autoloader, It doesn't care, rely only on updated (or not) buildpath until I'll finally drop DLTK integration :P

Comment: yeah sorry I didn't realise I was asking about phpunit as I didn't re-read. When I asked originally I was getting php autoloader failure in phpuni **and** unrecognised namespaces in Eclipse, now it is Eclipse only as PSR-4 fixes that as you suggest

Comment: Anyway, composer update sometimes driving me crazy in eclipse, so I soon fix refresh buildpath problem. For now I'm concentrated on GitHub migration ;)

Comment: Glad to find out that I'm not the only one with difficulties!

Comment: zulus, I am not sure if your comment is providing a full solution to the part about Eclipse PDT problems but it is at least helpful in respect to autoloader debugging, could you please integrate your comment starting 'You don't have to remove/add composer..' into your answer and I will award the bounty